# Software updater gets stuck

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

As of late Software Updater gets frozen (won't close after checking), while

```
sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

work fine. Any ideas or anybody else with the same problem?

I have Xubuntu 14.04 x64.

**Update:** The final answer to my question is that I have a broken system, which most probably happened when I completely removed Steam and its repository. It so happens that I've lost AbiWord, Bomi and some other apps from different PPAs and cannot reinstall them until I fix broken packages which include gcc-4.9 and four other files.

I'll wait till April for a clean install of the next stable release.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix the software center by reinstalling it.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
```

Comment: No, the software center is fine. It's the Software Updater that freezes. Besides, reinstalling update-manager, didn't help any.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

This is basically you installing from software updater

Comment: How does this help the person who updated their post to say they had a broken system? Using `dist-upgrade` will fail if a person does not have a relatively up-to-date installation already, so there's little chance ramming through a version upgrade will solve this particular problem 